# Move an Oracle table to being Index Organised

Tags: oracle

I have an Oracle table in a live production environment and the table is over half a gig in size. Is it possible to change this normal Oracle table from being heap organised to index organised or is this only achievable by moving the data from this table to another new table which is index organised? Either way, I would be grateful if you could you please list the steps involved in this procedure.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to alter a table to make it index-organized table. Instead you can redefine the table(using [DBMS_REDEFINITION](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_redefi.htm))or can create new table using CTAS.

Example:

```
 create table t2 (
 id number, first_name varchar2(20),
 constraint pk_id primary key (id)
 )
 organization index
 as select * from t1;
```

Comment: Thanks JSapkota. I have seen the same comment on other websites and was interested in a little more elaboration on how to use the DBMS_REDEFINITION package. For instance using the same SQL above, how would one use the DBMS_REDEFINITION package, so that a new table t2 does not have to be created, but t1 is transformed using the package.

Comment: You also need to create new interim table with new physical structure(here you can define the organization of the table) to redefine your table and its a quite lengthy process. This documentation link provides some useful examples:http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables007.htm

Comment: Does this work without specifying a primary key? An IOT must have a primary key.

Comment: @TS74 - Using `dbms_redefinition` still requires that you create a new table `t2`, move the data over, and then do a rename.  What that package does, however, it to let you do that (mostly) online by using other technologies to do things like track changes on the old table so that they can be applied to the new table in order to minimize downtime.  You could do the same thing yourself with materialized views and MV logs but `dbms_redefinition` is a nice abstraction layer so you don't have to think about all those internals.

Answer (score 1):

I never used `DBMS_REDEFINITION` but with CTAS it is not only step to create table if it is production.

1. List all indexes, constraints, foreign keys and so on based on system views
2. Prepare create index, constraints and alter foreign keys statements. prepare list of triggers, procedures that depend on table.
3. Create table as select (consider lock before that step if you can)
4. Create all indexes, constraints with prepared statements from step 2
5. Swap table names and swap foreign keys (this step may cause some errors if you hit insert on foreign keys (if you expect it on that time you should lock the table and tables referencing by foreign key).
6. Compile dependent objects from 2 (if you locked tables unlock here)
7. (if you haven't locked on step 3) Insert into table `select * from new minus select * from old;` or if you have timstamp of inserting row just insert new rows.

I hope the list is complete.